# Update ProgressBar from Program Class not working

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I'm trying to figure out why my progressbar isn't updating. I'm trying to update from my program class.

I specifically want to update it from my program class, because I'm going to perform a task and feed it an update value.

The for loop is just for testing.

Program.cs

```
namespace CacheMonitor
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 myform = new Form1();
            Application.Run(myform);


            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                myform.UpdateProgress(i);

            }

       }
    }
}
```

Form.cs

```
namespace CacheMonitor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void UpdateProgress(int newValue)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = newValue;
        }

  }
```

}

Comment: You probably want a background worker/async method to do this

Comment: `Application.Run(myform);` blocks the code under it.  So use a timer or a background thread instead.

Comment: If you put the update progress code inside the form itself, and use a timer to kick it off, you'll see the updates.  Issue it that changes to the control have to happen in the UI thread, and that is locked up in the `Application.Run(myform)` line.